# Material texture split through the middle

Tags: texturing, materials

I have applied a material texture to the floor, but it seems like it has a split through the middle distorting the view, can someone help. Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you share the blend file https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=elQwESaP" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/elQwESaP/)

Comment: The UVMap is bad of the floor. Unwrap it again, or use an other Texture Coordinate.

Comment: Can you please explain how this could be done?

Comment: Thanks @FFeller I have unwrapped it and its now fine!